# Porque me muestra todas las imagenes y no una?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

en mi tabla yo contengo un campo que se llama remito que iría una imagen del remito. Hasta ahora todo bien en mi base de datos se guarda la ruta del archivo y en la vista me muestra la ruta del archivo. Lo que hice despues es agregar un boton para visualizar la imagen en si y no la ruta, pero al seleccionar el boton de visualizar me muestra todas las imagenes y no la del que seleccione. Es como si no me estuviese identificando mi id.

Lo siguiente es el modal que cree donde se muestra la imagen:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DetalleTicketView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1050; display:none; width:100%" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="max-width:75%;">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Detalle del Ticket</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table id="example1" class="table table-striped table-responsive" width="100%">
                            
                            <tbody>
                               
                                @foreach($file as $key => $detalleTicket)
                                <tr>                                   
                                    
                                    <td style="display: none">{{ $key+1 }}</td>
                                    
                                    <img src="{{asset('storage/' . $detalleTicket->remitoCliente)}}" alt="">
                                
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        </div>
```

Este seria el boton con la data del modal:

```
<a title="Info" id="info" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-idUpdate="'.$detalleTicket->id.'" data-target="#DetalleTicketView"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Este sería mi controlador de DetalleTicket:

```
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;

   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Auth;
   use Session;
   use App\Model\DetalleTicket;
   use App\Model\Ticket;
   use App\Model\Product;


 class DetalleTicketController extends Controller
  {
    public function view(){ 
       $file = DetalleTicket::all();
       return view('backend.detalle_ticket.view-detalle-ticket', compact('file'));
   }

public function add(){
    $detalleTicket['tickets'] = Ticket::all();        
    $detalleTicket['products'] = Product::all();
    
    return view('backend.detalle_ticket.add-detalle-ticket', $detalleTicket);
}

public function store(Request $request){
    /*dd($request->all());*/
    $detalleTicket = new DetalleTicket();

    $detalleTicket->ticket_id = $request->ticket_id;
    $detalleTicket->product_id = $request->product_id;
    $detalleTicket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
    $detalleTicket->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $detalleTicket->commentary = $request->commentary;
    $path = request()->file('remitoCliente')->store('archivos'); 
    $detalleTicket->remitoCliente = $path;
    
    $detalleTicket->save();
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view', $path);
}

public function edit($id){
    $data['editData'] = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    $data['tickets'] = Ticket::all();
    $data['products'] = Product::all();
    
    
    return view('backend.detalle_ticket.edit-detalle-ticket', $data);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $detalleTicket = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    
           
    $detalleTicket->ticket_id = $request->ticket_id;
    $detalleTicket->product_id = $request->product_id;
    $detalleTicket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
    $detalleTicket->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $detalleTicket->commentary = $request->commentary;
    $path = request()->file('remitoCliente')->store('archivos'); 
    $detalleTicket->remitoCliente = $path;
    
    $detalleTicket->save();
    
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view');
}

public function delete($id){
    $detalleTicket = DetalleTicket::find($id);
    $detalleTicket->delete();
    return redirect()->route('detalles-tickets.view');
}
```

}

Es decir si yo agrego un ticket con una imagen y luego agrego otro con otra imagen, cuando apreto en el boton para visualizar me aparecen ambas fotos una arriba de la otra.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas al modal ya tienes todas las imágenes cargadas en él, y lo que debes hacer es usar AJAX.

Ejemplo:

creas el modal con un img y le das un ID
Cuando selecciones la imagen a mostrar, la etiqueta tendrá una metadata con el id que corresponde a la imagen.
con ese meta realizas la consulta ajax hacia el Backend y obtienes la ruta reletava y la retornas ya con ese resultado actualizas el modal

> Actualización de respuesta con sugerencia

```
<!-- Le asignas la misma clase -->
<html>
@foreach(<!-- Obten los id de cada reporte IMG -->)
<li class="nombre_de_clase" id="{{_id}}"></li> 
@endforeach

<div class="modal fade" id="DetalleTicketView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1050; display:none; width:100%" aria-hidden="true">
    <img src="" id="DetalleTicketViewImg" alt="">
</div>




<script>
  $(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".nombre_de_clase", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var id =
        $(this).attr("id"); /* ID del elemento al que se le ha hecho "click" */

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{route('URL_DEL_BACKEND')}}",
        headers: {
          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("input[name=token]").val(), /*Donde tengas guardado el token CSRF*/
        },
        data: {
          _id: id,
        },
      }).done(function (url) {
        $("#DetalleTicketViewImg").attr("src", "{{url}}?" + d.getTime()); /*el final d.getTime es para que el navegador actualice la img*/
        $("#DetalleTicketView").modal("show");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

Adapta el Backend a tu solución

```
<!-- Backend -->

public function obtenerURL(Request $request){
    $_id =  $request->get('_id')
    /**@todo Buscas la url de la img por ese ID*/
    return response()->json({'url':url_obtenida});
}
```

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo para mostrarme?

Comment: Te lo formulo en unos minutos

Comment: Dale muchas gracias.

Comment: Puede agregar un Loading mientras se ejecuta el ajax, para que notifique al usuario que está realizando una operación